# SImilarities between exec and os.system()

Tags: python, c

I am new to multi-threaded programming in python.

Can someone tell me whether os.system("ls") in python and exec("ls") call in "C" are doing the same ?
Please tell me about the similarities and dissimilarities as well.

Comment: This can be answered simply by reading the docs.  From [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system): "[os.system] is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and has the same limitations".  So all you need to do now is look up the two C functions `system` and `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, `exec(whatever)` **replaces** the current process's code with the code from `whatever`.  Thus, it never returns.  You can do the same in Python with `os.execv` and friends -- see https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-management .

`os.system(whatever)`, on the other hands, **forks** the current process, execs `whatever` **in the subprocess**, waits for it to end, then returns.  So, it's the same as `system(whatever)` is in C: a simple layer on top of `fork`, `exec`, and `wait` system calls (in Unix-like systems; simulated by other means in non-Unix-based systems, of which I believe the only one around in substantial numbers these days is Microsoft Windows).